# MaxMetaSpace and CompressedClassSpaceSize

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, metaspace

Can I understand when UseCompressedClassPointers is enabled, MaxMetaspace is not relevance and CompressedClassSpaceSize determines the size of the metaspace?.

Because from Oracle doc
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html (section Exception in thread thread_name: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Compressed class space)

- *If the UseCompressedClassPointers is used, the amount of space

  available for class metadata is fixed at the amount

  CompressedClassSpaceSize. If the space needed for

  UseCompressedClassPointers exceeds CompressedClassSpaceSize, a

  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError with detail Compressed class space is

  thrown.*

kindly point me to some link that explains what is stored in CompressedClassSpaceSize & Metaspace

Comment: Metaspace may contain more meta data than class metadata.

Answer (score 3):

> CompressedClassSpaceSize determines the size of the metaspace

No, it's incorrect. Compressed class space is an memory region inside Metaspace. So MaxMetaspaceSize option always works and limits both Metaspace and inner Compressed class space.
If you try to set CompressedClassSpaceSize greater than MaxMetaspaceSize it will not make an effect.
See [Is CompressedClassSpaceSize area contains MaxMetaspaceSize area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54250638/is-compressedclassspacesize-area-contains-maxmetaspacesize-area)
See also https://stuefe.de/posts/metaspace/what-is-metaspace/