# Is CompressedClassSpaceSize area contains MaxMetaspaceSize area?

Tags: java, jvm

What is `CompressedClassSpaceSize`?

What is the relationship  between `CompressedClassSpaceSize` and `MetaspaceSize`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Metaspace** is the memory area for storing class metadata - internal JVM structures created while parsing `.class` files.

Class metadata includes:

- Internal representation of Java classes
- Methods with their bytecode
- Field descriptors
- Constant pools
- Symbols
- Annotations
- etc.

`-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` is unlimited by default.

When `-XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers` option is ON (default for heaps < 32G), classes are moved from Metaspace to the separate area called **Compressed Class Space**. This is to allow addressing VM class structures with 32-bit values instead of 64-bit.

So, Compressed Class Space contains internal representation of Java classes, while Metaspace holds all the rest metadata: methods, constant pools, annotations, etc.

The size of Compressed Class Space is limited by `-XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize`, which is 1G by default. The maximum possible value of `-XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize` is 3G.

Non-class Metaspace and Compressed Class Space are two disjoint areas. `MaxMetaspaceSize` limits the committed size of both areas:

```
committed(Non-class Metaspace) + committed(Compressed Class Space) <= MaxMetaspaceSize
```

If `MaxMetaspaceSize` is set smaller than `CompressedClassSpaceSize`, the latter is automatically decreased to

```
CompressedClassSpaceSize = MaxMetaspaceSize - 2*InitialBootClassLoaderMetaspaceSize
```