# JVM always reserved nearly 1G memory in my linux server according to pmap

Tags: memory, jvm, pmap

I wrote a java class and run it in linux.  JVM always reserve nearly 1G memory No matter how big the heap size is. I tried

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx512m  MemTe
java -Xms100m -Xmx100m  MemTe
java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m  MemTe
```

There is always a line in pmap,Value is 1048064  104768.....

```
000000000204c000     132      12      12 rw---   [ anon ]
00000000e0000000  524800    4368    4368 rw---   [ anon ](It's heap size)
0000000100080000 1048064       0       0 -----   [ anon ]

00000000018f9000     132      12      12 rw---   [ anon ]
00000000f9c00000  102912    2320    2320 rw---   [ anon ](It's heap size)
0000000100080000 1048064       0       0 -----   [ anon ]


000000000176d000     132      12      12 rw---   [ anon ]
0000000080000000 2098048   13104   13104 rw---   [ anon ](It's heap size)
00000001000e0000 1047680       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
```

Linux server has 6VCPU 16GB memory

Anyone can explain why?
Thanks

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MemTe {
  static volatile boolean RUN = false;
  static String s = null;
  static int tcnt;

  public static void main(String args[]) throws {
    List<String> st = new ArrayList<>();
    while (System.in.read() > 0) {
      RUN = false;
      Thread t = new Thread(MemTe::go);
      t.start();
      tcnt++;
      System.out.println("Threads: " + tcnt);
      System.out.println(System.in.read());
      RUN = true;

      st.add(s);
    }

  }

  private static void go() {
    while (true) {
      while (RUN) {           
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId());
        s = new String("s");

        try {
          Thread.sleep(100000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Compressed Class Space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54254531/3448419).
Its default size is exactly 1G; can be modified with `-XX:CompressedClassSpaceSize`.

The virtual memory for the whole Compressed Class Space is initially *reserved*, but not *committed*, i.e. it does not take physical memory. The pages are committed on demand as the usage of Compress Class Space grows. That's why in `pmap` output you'll see two neighbor regions: the first (with `rw` protection attributes) is committed, and the rest is reserved (RSS=0).

```
0000000100000000     512     260     260 rw---   [ anon ]
0000000100080000 1048064       0       0 -----   [ anon ]
```

[More about JVM virtual memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53624438/3448419)

Comment: Thinks you for your helpful answer.  Another question is why the RSS and dirty is 0 ?  I tried create difference class instance in main method. But the RSS value is not changed . always 0 as your pasted link.

Comment: I think the Compress Class Space committed size should not be 0 when the main function running because classloader has loaded some classes to the space . But it's 0 actually. That‘s my new question.

Comment: @FFMan It's not zero. In your case committed space starts at `100000000` and ends at `100080000` or `1000e0000`. Since it is adjacent to heap and has the same protection attributes, it is shown as the single region together with heap.